# how to use jQuery to export table with pagination to excel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how can i use `jQuery` or `JavaScript` to export data from `table` with `pagination` to Excel.

i try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tableToExcel = (function() {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()
    </script>
```

But i can export only one page of the pagination i want to export all data in table. What can i do??

Comment: i believe you are doing pagination at server side and bringing only 1 page data to frontend. so in order to get all data, make a server request for export-data, query all data from db and fputcsv. this would be the easiest way to achieve that.

Comment: @Gunnrryy can u show me your script answer

Answer (score 1):

1. make a file export_data.php
2. put your query condition in export_data.php

for eg.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $file_name = 'All Users.csv';
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $file_name");
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

3. make ajax request to export_data.php

this should get you your complete data. You need to change the sql as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your script gets all data by removing limits in your query.

Comment: which script i should remove??